# Python get selenium to react to browser notifications (Chrome)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

Is there any way to get selenium to listen and react to browser notifications like an email or a whatsapp web notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah sure! I am presenting you an example where i intentionally make google create a fake browser notification (just for a demo). You just check the `alert.dismiss()` line.

**Here we go :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("<your path to chromedriver>")
driver.get("http://google.com")

# Creating a fake notification. Just ignore this.
driver.execute_script("window.alert('This is an alert');")
time.sleep(2)

# Now here's what you are looking for
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.dismiss()
```